# Iterate over pandas dataframe column, search for parentheses and delete them (and everything inside of it)

Tags: python, pandas, parentheses

I have want to achieve the following. I have a pandas dataframe containing the column "email". I want to iterate over the rows in this column and search in each cell for the parentheses. Besides that I want to delete the parentheses as well and delete everything inside of it so for example:

"Steen, A.K. (Test) de" should be "Steen, A.K. de"
"Lastname, T. (Test)" should be "Lastname, T."

Can anyone help me with this?

Searched a lot on the web. I'm still learning programming in Python but I found it very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.replace(r'\s*\(.*\)\s*', '', regex=True)
```

If you want to keep the intermediate space:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.replace(r'\s*\(.*\)\s*?(\s(?=.))?', r'\1', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
         col_name
0  Steen, A.K. de
1    Lastname, T.
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name': ["Steen, A.K. (Test) de", "Lastname, T. (Test)"]})
```